# Issue with UITableViewCells Repeating Content

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

My app shows the user local bus departures however when Night Buses start to show the red 'N' shows in other services after scrolling as shown in the screenshots below, additionally the route numbers start to be wrong. The route numbers are correct the rest of the time when scrolling, it is only when the Night Buses appear

[image: After opening the app]

[image: Night Buses at the bottom of the Table]

[image: Scrolling back up the app]

This is the code I have executed for setting the route number

```
case "N3", "N7", "N11","N16","N22","N25","N26","N30","N31","N34", "N37","N44","N98", "N106","N113","N124":

var route = NSMutableAttributedString()

route = NSMutableAttributedString(string: departureRoutes[0].rawString()!)

route.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.red, range: NSRange(location:0,length:1))

route.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.white, range: NSRange(location:1,length:(departureRoutes[0].string?.count)! - 1))

cell.route.setAttributedTitle(route, for: .normal)       

default : 

cell.route.tintColor = routeColor(routeno: departureRoutes[0].rawString()!)
```

Comment: Table view cells are reused. Only set cell UI element values in 'cellForRowAtIndexPath', and remember to set all UI element values so values won't rollover from one cell to the next.

Comment: @FryAnEgg This code is being run in cellForRowAt indexPath

Comment: Like @FryAnEgg mentioned, you need to set every view within a cell every time. Any you don’t set because of conditional code will stay the same when the cell is reused when the user scrolls.

Comment: I only see one attributed string and one tine color being set. You can always step through cellForRow to track what data is going into your cells.

Comment: Classic mistake :-) Could you provide the whole cellForRow function and well formatted code?

Comment: As it shows route is a UIButton and i thinks you sometimes set title & other you set attributtedTitle, you should reset both title & attributtedTitle by empty strings before setting you values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was as suggested by Mohamed Mostafa in the comments was to reset the value of the UIButton and set the value again using

```
cell.route.setAttributedTitle(NSMutableAttributedString(string: "\(departureRoutes[indexPath.row + 1])"), for: .normal)
```

Then performing the switch code after this